# Wordpress Multisite Permalinks Not Saving

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, permalinks, multisite

The permalinks for some of the network sites will reset to the url of the main site.

Example:
`example.com/site1` will occasionally reset to `example.com`

This started happening after installing an SSL on the server.

In the apache sites-enabled config file I have a SSL VirtualHost

```
#SSL VirtualHost
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

SSLEngine ON
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/example.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/example.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/example.crt

ErrorLog logs/ssl.domain.com.error_log
CustomLog logs/ssl.domain.com.access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and my `.htaccess` looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>



# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# uploaded files
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```